# Как наложить текст поверх UI-элемента?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Обычно нужно по порядку располагать в иерархии, но в моём случае это не работает, так как текст в разных объектах, если у маленького окна на картинке фон с порядком отрисовки 0, то происходит (картинка 1), если увеличить уровень отрисовки хотя бы до 1, то происходит (картинка 2), как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: предлагаю не лезть в настройки отрисовки вовсе и все выставить в одном слое. И тогда не будет никаких проблем - как выставишь слоя в иерархии - так и будет отрисовываться. А то сначала сам себе проблемы создаешь, а потом ищешь как бы их побороть...)

Comment: В таком случае происходит (картинка 1), на 3м скрине они все в одном слое, в иерархии, но...

Comment: Ну значит все как нужно. Осталось отключить из иерархии лишние элементы которых быть не должнов этом экране настроек. И слои отрисовки здесь не при чем)

Comment: То есть им можно SetActive(false) и не париться, интересно, спасибо

Comment: только советую разные меню разнести по иерархии. Что бы включать просто родительский элемент иерархии а не парится с кучей разных

Comment: Всё же получается костыль, в других сценах с UI-элементами также придётся их скрывать, а для этого - искать каждый элемент, возможно, стоит поместить настройки в другой Canvas и работать через сортировку полотен

Comment: это может быть костылем потому что ты что-то криво делаешь. Я написал ответ как бы сделал бы я.

Answer (score 0):

1. создаешь один канвас
2. делаешь на канвасе кучу пустых обьектов. Один обьект - одно меню
3. На сам канвас навешиваешь один скрипт который ищет дочерние элементы и может их включать и выключать.
4. У скрипта должен быть метод "скрыть все меню". И по методу на включение и отключение каждого отдельного меню.
5. Размещаешь элементы в одном слое отрисовки. А потом просто размещаешь по иерархии в инспекторе их как тебе необходимо.
6. Перед стартом все меню должны быть включены иначе дочерние менюхи могут не найтись.
7. По запуску сразу же скрываешь все меню и показываешь дальше только необходимые в зависимости от контекста.